# undefined function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I call the `search_array` function, I get this error:

```
Call to undefined function search_array()
```

Even if I make all the function public, it doesn't work. How is this possible?

```
 function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
     if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
          return true;
     }
     foreach($haystack as $element) {
          if(is_array($element) && search_array($needle, $element))
               return true;
     }
   return false;
}

public function do(){
   $excist = $this->search_array($test[2], $allValuta);
}
```

Comment: Because you're trying to call a function instead of the method. `search_array($needle, $element)` should be `$this->search_array($needle, $element)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your codes to be like this:

```
function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
     if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
          return true;
     }
     foreach($haystack as $element) {
          if(is_array($element) && $this->search_array($needle, $element))
               return true;
     }
   return false;
}

public function do(){
   $excist = $this->search_array($test[2], $allValuta);
}
```

Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter, to call a function you should use `$this->`. So add `$this->` to `search_array()`

Like this,

```
if(is_array($element) && search_array($needle, $element))
```

to

```
f(is_array($element) && $this->search_array($needle, $element))
                        ^     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a class ?
If not, you are defining a **function** search_array().
So you should not call it with **$this->**search_array(...), this scheme is the use for a method of a class.

In short : remove the **$this->**